# How do I recover my missing files

Tags: windows, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, hard-drive-recovery

I have a Windows 7 computer that I put iTunes on.  I have an external hard drive.  I had iTunes organize my music in the external hard drive into a different directory.  I now find that all my mp3's are missing.

I assume they haven't all been deleted off my hard drive, so how can I recover them?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Recuva, one of the best tools, to recollect the deleted files.

[Here is Link to download Recuva](https://www.piriform.com/recuva)

Note: You should not write new files into your hard disk after deletion. Because Deletion means OS remove just Link to that file saying that the place is available for filling. Then there can chances to fill that place if write new files into hard disk. So if you want to recover the files then avoid writing new files onto disk.

Answer (score 1):

One of the best free file recovery solutions for windows is Recuva
https://www.piriform.com/recuva/download

But make sure you do not install the Programm to the Harddisk with the deleted files.